# JS, возможно ли увеличить радиус клика?

Tags: javascript

В общем, вопрос состоит в заголовке.

Возможно ли увеличить/изменить радиус клика? Если да, то как?

Объясню зачем: допустим, canvas-ом сымитировали дождь. Т.е. сверху с рандомных координат опускаются "капли дождя". Я хочу добиться того, чтобы onclick можно было охватить несколько "капель".

Comment: а сейчас он какой - радиус клика?

Comment: @Igor, к сожалению, мне это не известно

Comment: можно увеличить размер невидимой зоны спрайта, который вы используете как каплю, тогда не нужно будет изобретать велосипед

Comment: @РусланДраган, что такое спрайт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

берешь позицию курсора 
затем позицию капли

выясняешь расстояние между ними (диагональ)
сравниваешь свой "радиус клика" с диагональю если <= тогда берешь эту каплю
и так с каждой каплей

Comment: О, благодарю. Хорошее решение)